# Protected vars using ReflectionClass

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to read protected vars by called class. Where is the problem with my protected $test and new ReflectionClass?

```
<?PHP
class foo
{
    protected $test = ['foo' => 'foo'];
    public function __construct()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();

        do
        {
            foreach((new \ReflectionClass($class))->getDefaultProperties() as $property => $value)
                var_dump([$class.'::'.$property => $value]);
        }
        while($class = get_parent_class($class));
    }
}

class baz extends foo
{
    protected $test = ['baz' => 'baz'];
}

new baz;
```

actual:

```
  ["baz::test"]=>
    ["baz"]=> "baz"
  ["foo::test"]=>
    ["baz"]=> "baz"
```

expected:

```
  ["baz::test"]=>
    ["baz"]=> "baz"
  ["foo::test"]=>
    ["foo"]=> "foo"
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem. The `$test` class variable in your parent class is set to:

```
array
(
   'foo' => 'foo'
)
```

And the child class which inherits it overrides the value of the array (it doesn't add to the array, but replaces all the existing keys/values) with:

```
array
(
   'baz' => 'baz'
)
```

Comment: Even though I create a new instance of ReflectionClass(string parentClassName) - not by the instance of Baz?

How I can detect the parents with ReflectionClass?

Comment: Yes. Inheritance, as defined in the PHP manual, means that "the extended or derived class has all variables and functions of the base class". All you're doing in Baz is overriding one variable.

Comment: @fruffl are you satisfied with the problem or do you want to discuss it more? If not, you can mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: I've found the accept-button \o/ I wrote a workaround to merge recursively static protected configs from called class: pastebin.com/WVnDmNfd